# Future result update UI as soon as they arrive

Tags: java, future

I have `JList` using `DefaultListModel` to update the strings in list in UI , returned by a class as shown

```
class ResponseGiver implements Callable<Future>{

        int i;

       //Constructor to initialize i

     String call(){
      ...............
      ...............
      return i;
  }
```

and i have other class that will update the results obtained from above

```
class Viewer {

    ExecutorService es = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
      {
         futures.add(new ResponseGiver(i));
      }
 for(Future<String> x : futures)  //loop 2nd will be called 10 times
  {
     String p = x.get(); 
       //update GUI with p
   }
```

Now the question is, suppose in loop 2nd , in the 5th loop, the `get()` function takes some time say 10 seconds, and during the mean time, the other futures from 6th to 10th have their result ready.
So my screen would wait for 5th result, even 6th to 10th are ready.
I want my screen to be updated as soon as any of the 10 futures return the result.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard API, you can use a [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). It allows submitting `Callable` instances and returns `Future` objects, just like a normal `ExecutorService`. But it additionally allows obtaining the `Future` objects in the order in which they are finished: Using the [ExecutorCompletionService#take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#take%28%29) method. This method blocks until a new `Future` is available. You can imagine this as the `Futures` being placed into a blocking queue.

You can start a thread that consumes these `Future` objects from the completion service. The result of such a `Future` may then be used to update the GUI. (Note that this update, in turn, has to be done on the Event Dispatch Thread again, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ExecutorCompletionServiceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Run");
        f.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final Callback callback = new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void call(final String result)
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        listModel.addElement(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                createTasks(callback);
            }
        });

        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    interface Callback
    {
        void call(String result);
    }


    private static Random random = new Random(0);

    static class ResponseGiver implements Callable<String>
    {
        private int i;

        ResponseGiver(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public String call()
        {
            int delayMS = 250 + random.nextInt(500);

            // Simulate a longer delay for task 5
            if (i == 5)
            {
                delayMS += 3000;
            }
            try
            {
                System.out.println("For "+i+" waiting "+delayMS+" ms");
                Thread.sleep(delayMS);
                System.out.println("For "+i+" waiting "+delayMS+" ms DONE");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            return String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }

    private static void createTasks(final Callback callback)
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        final CompletionService<String> executorCompletionService =
            new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executorService);
        final int n = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            executorCompletionService.submit(new ResponseGiver(i));
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                processResults(executorCompletionService, n, callback);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    private static void processResults(
        CompletionService<String> completionService, int n, Callback callback)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Future<String> future = completionService.take();
                String result = future.get();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    callback.call(result);
                }
                System.out.println("Processed "+(i+1)+" of "+n+" results");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`ListenableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) from guava. It's much more convenient.